# Proof that each square matrix has eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have an $n \times n$  matrix $B$ over $\mathbb{C}^n$. How can I show that $B$ has at least one eigenvector, aka prove that for some $x$ we have $(A - \lambda I) x = 0$?

Comment: fundamental theorem of algebra

Comment: @BigbearZzz That shows that there's an eigenvalue, not an eigenvector.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra tells you that there is a complex number $\lambda$ such that $A-\lambda I$ has determinant zero. You now need to argue that if a matrix $B$, has determinant zero then it has a nontrivial kernel, i.e. there is a nonzero vector $x$ with $Bx=0$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr if there's an eigenvalue, there's an eigenvector as well ...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Of course, that was likely unknown to the OP.

Comment: Then you are assuming that the OP did not know what "eigenvector" **meant**?

Comment: ...I can assure everyone I know what eigenvalues/vectors are, if that is in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any nonzero vector $x$ and consider the $n+1$ vectors $\{ x, Ax, A^2, \cdots, A^{n-1}x, A^n x\}$.

They are linearly dependent and hence there exist $\{a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n\}$, not all zero, s.t.

$$a_0 x+a_1Ax+a_2A^2x+\cdots+a_nA^nx=0$$

Suppose only $a_0$ is nonzero, then

$$a_0 x =0 \implies x=0,$$
Constradiction.
So there exist largest integer $m\ge1$ s.t. $a_m\ne0$.

WLOG we can let $a_m=1$

By fundamental theorem of algebra, we have

$$a_0I+a_1A+\cdots+a_mA^m=(A-b_m I)(A-b_{m-1}I)\cdots(A-b_2I)(A-b_1I)$$

$$0=(A-b_mI_n)(A-b_{m-1}I)\cdots(A-b_2I)(A-b_1I)x$$

Let $k$ be the smaller integer s.t.

$$(A-b_kI)(A-b_{k-1}I)\cdots(A-b_1 I)x=0$$

Then by definition

$$z=(A-b_{k-1}I)\cdots(A-b_1 I)x\ne0$$
and

$$(A-b_kI)z=0$$

$$Az=b_k z$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: what exactly is z? It seems to come out of nowhere

Comment: @jackwise By definition $k$ is the smallest integer so that $\left ( \prod_{i=1}^k (A-b_i I) \right )x=0$, so if you only multiply up to $k-1$ you get a nonzero vector, which Kyson denoted by $z$.

Comment: also, what are b_m...b_1? Are those meant to be eigenvalues?

Comment: @jackwise $b_1$ to $b_m$ are the $m$ roots of the polynomial $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_mx^m$.

Comment: @velutluna Can we be sure that $b_k\neq 0\,$?

Comment: @Michael_1812 Eigenvalue can be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:

Step 1: The characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.  By the fundamental theorem of algebra, this polynomial has at least one root, let $\lambda$ be a root of the characteristic polynomial.

Step 2: By construction, $\det(B-\lambda I)=0$.  This implies, by the invertible matrix theorem that $B-\lambda I$ is not invertible, $B-\lambda I$ is not full rank, etc.  In particular, if you row reduce the augmented matrix $\begin{bmatrix}B-\lambda I&|&\vec{0}\end{bmatrix}$, you will have a free variable.  By letting this free variable be something other than $0$, you can construct your eigenvector.